# How to send email based on CFM form selected value

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a javascript form that links and works perfectly to a .cfm form that sends an email to the correct people. I want to send an email to one person if option A is selected and to another person if option B is selected.

Do I do this with Javascript? If so how do i connect it to the .cfm email form?

something like:

> if (option == 'a')
>
> send email to john
>
> else if (option == 'b')
>
> send email to tom

What is the syntax to send the email? Should I be doing this with coldfusion syntax instead?

Comment: You could do it with either or, but it would be more secure to do it with coldfusion. If you send the target email address to coldfusion with javascript, anyone could modify your form to instead send it to anyone in the world.

Comment: Duncan's answer is correct if you simply submit an html form to a coldfusion page.  However, the phrase, I have a javascript form that links and works perfectly to a .cfm form" is troublesome.  If Duncan's answer does not work, and you still want help, you'll have to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 7):

In your .cfm file, it's as simple as:

```
<cfif form.option EQ "a">
  <cfset mailto="john@example.com">
<cfelseif form.option EQ "b">
  <cfset mailto="tom@example.com">
<cfelse>
<!--- you should have a default if option could be non-selected --->
  <cfset mailto="jane@example.com">
</cfif>

<cfmail to="#mailto#" ...>
```

OR if the user can only select from A or B, then you don't need the else-if part of this, and it can be simplified to:

```
<cfif form.option EQ "a">
  <cfset mailto="john@example.com">
<cfelse>
  <cfset mailto="tom@example.com">
</cfif>

<cfmail to="#mailto#" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, one thing to be aware of... if you are using a checkbox or radio button form element, HTML will NOT submit any value for that form element if the user doesn't select any value.

So I like to write my code like this:

```
<cfset option = "default">  <!--- setup whatever default value you want here --->
<cfif isDefined( "form.option" )>
   <cfset option = form.option>
</cfif>

<cfif option EQ "a">
   <cfset mailto="john@example.com">
<cfelseif option EQ "b">
   <cfset mailto="tom@example.com">
<cfelseif option EQ "default">
   <!--- you should have a default if option could be non-selected --->
  <cfset mailto="jane@example.com">
</cfif>

<cfmail to="#mailto#" ...>
```